# Match only particular special chars using regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I have the below code to take input with minimum 3 chars, it should contain only **[a-zA-Z0-9]** ,**_**,**-**,**.(dot)**
But the pattern should not match only **.**

Like input can be **--__abc** and **----**, *____* but can't be *...**

I have the below pattern, but not working properly.
Can someone help me

```
     n = input()
     pattern = "^[A-Za-z0-9_-]+[.]*$"
     if match:
         print('input accepted') # exp : ----,____,aaa,000, __ahs-- 
                                    -,_.as
     else:
         print('input not accepted') # exp : .... (not accepted as  
                                       contains only dot(.)
```

Comment: Looks like you need `if re.search(r'^(?!\s+$)[A-Za-z0-9._-]{2,}$', n.strip()):`

Comment: Thanks a lot @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Sorry, I meant `(?!\.+$)` of course, not `(?!\s+$)` :) In most cases, people ask about avoiding matching blank inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may fix the current approach by replacing the second and third lines in your above code with:

```
if re.search(r'^(?!\.+$)[A-Za-z0-9._-]{2,}$', n.strip()):
```

`n.strip()` will strip all redundant whitespace from the input and the pattern will match

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!\.+$)` - no dot only string allowed
- `[A-Za-z0-9._-]{2,}` - two or more letters, digits, `.`, `_` or `-`
- `$` - end of string.

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/V7UfpP/1).

Comment: Thanks Wiktor. Working as expected in python. But i am trying the same pattern for **Alpaca form** which is not working(only for **.....** input not working. Any idea about how to write for Alpaca form

Comment: @lokesh That is not Python. Try `/^(?!\.+$)[A-Za-z0-9._-]{2,}$/`, or `"^(?!\\.+$)[A-Za-z0-9._-]{2,}$"`

Comment: "^(?!\\.+$)[A-Za-z0-9._-]{2,}$" -- This is working for **Alpaca form**  Thanks a lot @Wiktor

Comment: How can i make changes so that the pattern doesn't allow for only **_** and **-** and doesn't allow special chars at beginning as well

Comment: @lokesh `^(?![._-]+$)[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9._-]+$'`

Comment: Thank you so much sir:)